# Where is implementation of basic methods like '+', '*', '/' (Arithmetic operators) in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

this may be the very beginning question and not only for Scala (I also want to know the same for Java), but where is implementation of basic methods in basic class?? For example, multiply operation has some overloaded methods and there is only written about interface. (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L392-L405)

But, when I look around there, nothing can be found. How can I know about their implementation??

Comment: I might be wrong, but in Java they are not regular methods, they are special operators (like `instanceof`, `public`, `synchronized` etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no actual implementation of those methods. To the JVM those methods don't even really exist. They are translated by the compiler to a [bytecode instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). For instance the method `+` on `Int` is translated to the `iadd` bytecode instruction.

You can see the bytecode that scalac generates in the REPL:
`iload` means "push a local variable on the stack". `iadd` pops two values from the stack, adds them as though they are integers and pushes the result back on the stack.

```
scala> class Foo { def foo(a: Int, b: Int) = a.+(b) }
defined class Foo

scala> :javap -c -p -filter Foo
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Foo {
  public int foo(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: iadd
       3: ireturn

  public Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #24                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

In case of [scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/) something similar happens, but instead of JVM bytecode, javascript code gets generated.